# python substitute a substring with one character less

Tags: python, regex

I need to process lines having a syntax similar to markdown http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax, where header lines in my case are something like:

```
=== a sample header ===
===== a deeper header =====
```

and I need to change their depth, i.e. reduce it (or increase it) so:

```
== a sample header ==
==== a deeper header ====
```

my small knowledge of python regexes is not enough to understand how to replace a number
n of '=' 's with (n-1) '=' signs

Comment: What if a line started with exactly one `=`?

Comment: Replace `=(=+)` with the backreference.

Comment: You can strip one `=` from both sides by using capturing group

Comment: @nhahtdh or simply using `str.lstrip` and `str.rstrip` ?

Comment: @InbarRose: No. Just in case there are spaces.

Comment: you don't need regular expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and two [negative lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to find two corresponding sets of `=` characters.

```
output = re.sub(r'(?<!=)=(=+)(.*?)=\1(?!=)', r'\1\2\1', input)
```

That will also work if you have a longer string that contains multiple headers (and will change all of them).

What does the regex do?

```
(?<!=)  # make sure there is no preceding =
=       # match a literal =
(       # start capturing group 1
  =+    # match one or more =
)       # end capturing group 1
(       # start capturing group 2
  .*?   # match zero or more characters, but as few as possible (due to ?)
)       # end capturing group 2
=       # match a =
\1      # match exactly what was matched with group 1 (i.e. the same amount of =)
(?!=)   # make sure there is no trailing =
```

Comment: strange... given s='==== 6.1.3 Earth ====', using your code I get '\x01\x02\x01'

Comment: @alessandro sorry, try again. I forgot to make the replacement a raw string.

Comment: yep, that's it! Thank you [goes back to the regex to understand what's happening]

Comment: as your answer to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13930044/1561176 wont this replace any '==' found throughout the input by mistake as well? all it takes is multiple '==' on the same line, if the input had copied text from some code it would be very possible.

Comment: @InbarRose yeah true, if you had two `==` on a single line then this would cause problems, too. I don't know about all assumptions you can make about markdown though. Of course, if a headline has to be the only thing on its, line you could replace the lookarounds by `^\s*` and `\s*$` and use multi-line mode, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

No need for regexes.  I would go very simple and direct:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    trimmed = line.strip()
    if len(trimmed) >= 2 and trimmed[0] == '=' and trimmed[-1] == '=':
        print(trimmed[1:-1])
    else:
        print line.rstrip()
```

The initial `strip` is useful because in Markdown people sometimes leave blank spaces at the end of a line (and maybe the beginning).  Adjust accordingly to meet your requirements.

Here is a [live demo](http://ideone.com/ATpeUa).

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be as simple as replacing `'=(=+)'` with `\1` .

Is there any reason for not doing so?

Comment: No, this is great if you know that the only `=` characters in your input will be in headlines. But if your file also contains code snippets with (unmatched) `==`, then you would turn all of these into `=`

Answer (score 0):

how about a simple solution?

```
lines = ['=== a sample header ===', '===== a deeper header =====']
new_lines = []
for line in lines:
    if line.startswith('==') and line.endswith('=='):
        new_lines.append(line[1:-1])
```

results:

```
['== a sample header ==', '==== a deeper header ====']
```

or in one line:

```
new_lines = [line[1:-1] for line in lines if line.startswith('==') and line.endswith('==')]
```

the logic here is that if it starts and ends with '==' then it must have at least that many, so when we remove/trim each side, we are left with at least '=' on each side.

this will work as long as each 'line' starts and ends with its '==....' and if you are using these as headers, then they will be as long as you strip the newlines off.

Answer (score 0):

either the first header or the second header,you can just use string replace like this

```
s = "=== a sample header ==="
s.replace("= "," "）
s.replace(" ="," ")
```

you can also deal with the second header like this

btw:you can also use the sub function of the re module，but it's not necessory

Comment: this will remove '=' from headers which only have 1. instead you should use `s.replace("== ","= ")` and `s.replace(" =="," =")` to make this approach work.